# client webpart multiline displays as one line only

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, client-webpart

I am trying to create a multiple line webpart property using this code: 

 `PropertyPaneTextField('test', {
                  label: 'Multi-line Text Field',
                  multiline: true
                }),`

As described in the docs, however, when i type multiple lines in the field, they're just displayed as one line only in the UI. Is there a way to let the user type what they want, and the result is displayed as is in the UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try escaping the property value and then replacing `%0A` with `<br/>`.
Like this
 `let propVal:string = escape(this.properties.test).replace(/%0A/g,"<br/>")`

Answer (score 1):

when you use `multiline: true` property, it enables you to enter the number of rows you want to display via the property `rows?: number`. This will help you display text field as text area.

```
PropertyPaneTextField('test', {
                  label: 'Multi-line Text Field',
                  multiline: true,
                  rows: 5
                }),
```

Comment: I just tried it, it doesn't have any effect. 

This is my code: `  PropertyPaneTextField('test', {
                  label: 'Multi-line Text Field',
                  multiline: true, 
                  rows: 5
                }), `  Still the output it displayed as one row, and it wraps when the div reaches the end, but I want the the text to be displayed the same way the user types it in the property.